# Error INSERTING INTO Table with SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlclient

I apologize if this is a repeat question, but I can't seem to find my particular issue.  I know that a variable within my INSERT Statement is not getting assigned, based on my error, but every other example I have found shows which variable has the issue, and with my problem, it just seems as though no variables are getting a value?

```
private void insertListIntoSQL(List<string[]> authList)
{
      string connectionstring;  //Connection String Info
      SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
      cnn.Open();

       authList.RemoveAt(0);
       foreach(string[] auth in authList)
       {
            
        SqlCommand updateTable = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AuthSubmitAppLog (RECEIVED, STATUS_COMMENTS, AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER, CASE_MANAGER, ENTER_DATE, UPDATE_DATE, COMPLETED_BY, COMPLETED_DATETIME, CONTRACT_ENROLL_DATE, CONTRACT_DISENROLL_DATE, DIAGNOSIS_CODE, AUTHORIZATION_TYPE, AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_DETAIL, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_ID, MEMBERSHIP_ID, MEMBER_ADDRESS_1, MEMBER_ADDRESS_2, MEMBER_CITY, MEMBER_STATE, MEMBER_ZIP, REGION, MEMBER_PHONE, LINE_OF_BUSINESS, MEDICAID_NUMBER, MEDICARE_NUMBER, MEDICARE_TYPE, VENDOR_NAME, MCO_PROVIDER_NAME, LOCATION_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRATION_DATE, SERVICE_CATEGORY, DETAIL_NUMBERS, SERVICE_CODE, MODIFIER_1, MODIFIER_2, MODIFIER_3, MODIFIER_4, SUNDAY_UNITS, MONDAY_UNITS, TUESDAY_UNITS, WEDNESDAY_UNITS, THURSDAY_UNITS, FRIDAY_UNITS, SATURDAY_UNITS, TOTAL_UNITS, NOTES_TO_PROVIDER, CASE_TYPE, STATUS, ALTERNATIVE_CASE_NUMBERS, SERVICES_CT_ID) VALUES (@RECEIVED, @STATUS_COMMENTS, @AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER, @CASE_MANAGER, @ENTER_DATE, @UPDATE_DATE, @COMPLETED_BY, @COMPLETED_DATETIME, @CONTRACT_ENROLL_DATE, @CONTRACT_DISENROLL_DATE, @DIAGNOSIS_CODE, @AUTHORIZATION_TYPE, @AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_DETAIL, @MEMBER_NAME, @MEMBER_ID, @MEMBERSHIP_ID, @MEMBER_ADDRESS_1, @MEMBER_ADDRESS_2, @MEMBER_CITY, @MEMBER_STATE,@ MEMBER_ZIP, @REGION, @MEMBER_PHONE, @LINE_OF_BUSINESS, @MEDICAID_NUMBER, @MEDICARE_NUMBER, @MEDICARE_TYPE, @VENDOR_NAME, @MCO_PROVIDER_NAME, @LOCATION_ID, @EFFECTIVE_DATE, @EXPIRATION_DATE, @SERVICE_CATEGORY, @DETAIL_NUMBERS, @SERVICE_CODE, @MODIFIER_1, @MODIFIER_2, @MODIFIER_3, @MODIFIER_4, @SUNDAY_UNITS, @MONDAY_UNITS, @TUESDAY_UNITS, @WEDNESDAY_UNITS, @THURSDAY_UNITS, @FRIDAY_UNITS, @SATURDAY_UNITS, @TOTAL_UNITS, @NOTES_TO_PROVIDER, @CASE_TYPE, @STATUS, @ALTERNATIVE_CASE_NUMBERS, @SERVICES_CT_ID)");
            updateTable.Connection = cnn;
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RECEIVED", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[0].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS_COMMENTS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[1].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  auth[2].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CASE_MANAGER", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[3].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENTER_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(auth[4]).ToString().Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UPDATE_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(auth[5]).ToString().Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPLETED_BY", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[6].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPLETED_DATETIME", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = auth[7].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTRACT_ENROLL_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(auth[8]).ToString().Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTRACT_DISENROLL_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(auth[9]).ToString().Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIAGNOSIS_CODE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[10].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AUTHORIZATION_TYPE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[11].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_DETAIL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[12].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEMBER_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[13].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEMBER_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[14].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEMBERSHIP_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[15].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEMBER_ADDRESS_1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[16].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEMBER_ADDRESS_2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[17].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEMBER_CITY", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[18].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEMBER_STATE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[19].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEMBER_ZIP", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[20].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REGION", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[21].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEMBER_PHONE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[22].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LINE_OF_BUSINESS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[23].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEDICAID_NUMBER", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[24].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEDICARE_NUMBER", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[25].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEDICARE_TYPE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[26].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VENDOR_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[27].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MCO_PROVIDER_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[28].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOCATION_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[29].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EFFECTIVE_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = auth[30].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPIRATION_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = auth[31].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERVICE_CATEGORY", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[32].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DETAIL_NUMBERS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  auth[33].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERVICE_CODE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  auth[34].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODIFIER_1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  auth[35].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODIFIER_2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  auth[36].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODIFIER_3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  auth[37].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODIFIER_4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  auth[38].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUNDAY_UNITS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  auth[39].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MONDAY_UNITS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  auth[40].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TUESDAY_UNITS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[41].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WEDNESDAY_UNITS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[42].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@THURSDAY_UNITS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  auth[43].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FRIDAY_UNITS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[44].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SATURDAY_UNITS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[45].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TOTAL_UNITS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[46].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOTES_TO_PROVIDER", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[47].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[48].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CASE_TYPE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[49].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ALTERNATIVE_CASE_NUMBERS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[50].Normalize();
            updateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERVICES_CT_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = auth[51].Normalize();
            updateTable.ExecuteNonQuery();  //<-- Error occurs here.
        }
        cnn.Close();
    }
```

On my call for **updateTable.ExecuteNonQuery();** I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@".

Which does not allow me to really figure out what the issue is, can anyone recommend on what I should be fixing?  Thank you!

Comment: woulda' been easy to spot if your sql was not one huge line

Comment: The second param to AddWithValue is supposed to be that value, not the var type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a space at @ MEMBER_ZIP

Comment: I am such an idiot... Thank you for being more attentive than I.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extra space between @ and MEMBER_ZIP:

@MEMBER_STATE,@ MEMBER_ZIP, @REGION

Fix it:

@MEMBER_STATE, @MEMBER_ZIP, @REGION

```
    var sqlStr="INSERT INTO AuthSubmitAppLog (RECEIVED, STATUS_COMMENTS, AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER, CASE_MANAGER, ENTER_DATE, UPDATE_DATE, COMPLETED_BY, COMPLETED_DATETIME, CONTRACT_ENROLL_DATE, CONTRACT_DISENROLL_DATE, DIAGNOSIS_CODE, AUTHORIZATION_TYPE, AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_DETAIL, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_ID, MEMBERSHIP_ID, MEMBER_ADDRESS_1, MEMBER_ADDRESS_2, MEMBER_CITY, MEMBER_STATE, MEMBER_ZIP, REGION, MEMBER_PHONE, LINE_OF_BUSINESS, MEDICAID_NUMBER, MEDICARE_NUMBER, MEDICARE_TYPE, VENDOR_NAME, MCO_PROVIDER_NAME, LOCATION_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRATION_DATE, SERVICE_CATEGORY, DETAIL_NUMBERS, SERVICE_CODE, MODIFIER_1, MODIFIER_2, MODIFIER_3, MODIFIER_4, SUNDAY_UNITS, MONDAY_UNITS, TUESDAY_UNITS, WEDNESDAY_UNITS, THURSDAY_UNITS, FRIDAY_UNITS, SATURDAY_UNITS, TOTAL_UNITS, NOTES_TO_PROVIDER, CASE_TYPE, STATUS, ALTERNATIVE_CASE_NUMBERS, SERVICES_CT_ID) VALUES (@RECEIVED, @STATUS_COMMENTS, @AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER, @CASE_MANAGER, @ENTER_DATE, @UPDATE_DATE, @COMPLETED_BY, @COMPLETED_DATETIME, @CONTRACT_ENROLL_DATE, @CONTRACT_DISENROLL_DATE, @DIAGNOSIS_CODE, @AUTHORIZATION_TYPE, @AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_DETAIL, @MEMBER_NAME, @MEMBER_ID, @MEMBERSHIP_ID, @MEMBER_ADDRESS_1, @MEMBER_ADDRESS_2, @MEMBER_CITY, @MEMBER_STATE,@MEMBER_ZIP, @REGION, @MEMBER_PHONE, @LINE_OF_BUSINESS, @MEDICAID_NUMBER, @MEDICARE_NUMBER, @MEDICARE_TYPE, @VENDOR_NAME, @MCO_PROVIDER_NAME, @LOCATION_ID, @EFFECTIVE_DATE, @EXPIRATION_DATE, @SERVICE_CATEGORY, @DETAIL_NUMBERS, @SERVICE_CODE, @MODIFIER_1, @MODIFIER_2, @MODIFIER_3, @MODIFIER_4, @SUNDAY_UNITS, @MONDAY_UNITS, @TUESDAY_UNITS, @WEDNESDAY_UNITS, @THURSDAY_UNITS, @FRIDAY_UNITS, @SATURDAY_UNITS, @TOTAL_UNITS, @NOTES_TO_PROVIDER, @CASE_TYPE, @STATUS, @ALTERNATIVE_CASE_NUMBERS, @SERVICES_CT_ID)"

SqlCommand updateTable = new SqlCommand(sqlString)
```

Comment: Well, that would explain the error.. thank you for catching my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You've accidentally put a space in `@ MEMBER_ZIP`

Change this line:

```
SqlCommand updateTable = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AuthSubmitAppLog (RECEIVED, STATUS_COMMENTS, AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER, CASE_MANAGER, ENTER_DATE, UPDATE_DATE, COMPLETED_BY, COMPLETED_DATETIME, CONTRACT_ENROLL_DATE, CONTRACT_DISENROLL_DATE, DIAGNOSIS_CODE, AUTHORIZATION_TYPE, AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_DETAIL, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_ID, MEMBERSHIP_ID, MEMBER_ADDRESS_1, MEMBER_ADDRESS_2, MEMBER_CITY, MEMBER_STATE, MEMBER_ZIP, REGION, MEMBER_PHONE, LINE_OF_BUSINESS, MEDICAID_NUMBER, MEDICARE_NUMBER, MEDICARE_TYPE, VENDOR_NAME, MCO_PROVIDER_NAME, LOCATION_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRATION_DATE, SERVICE_CATEGORY, DETAIL_NUMBERS, SERVICE_CODE, MODIFIER_1, MODIFIER_2, MODIFIER_3, MODIFIER_4, SUNDAY_UNITS, MONDAY_UNITS, TUESDAY_UNITS, WEDNESDAY_UNITS, THURSDAY_UNITS, FRIDAY_UNITS, SATURDAY_UNITS, TOTAL_UNITS, NOTES_TO_PROVIDER, CASE_TYPE, STATUS, ALTERNATIVE_CASE_NUMBERS, SERVICES_CT_ID) VALUES (@RECEIVED, @STATUS_COMMENTS, @AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER, @CASE_MANAGER, @ENTER_DATE, @UPDATE_DATE, @COMPLETED_BY, @COMPLETED_DATETIME, @CONTRACT_ENROLL_DATE, @CONTRACT_DISENROLL_DATE, @DIAGNOSIS_CODE, @AUTHORIZATION_TYPE, @AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_DETAIL, @MEMBER_NAME, @MEMBER_ID, @MEMBERSHIP_ID, @MEMBER_ADDRESS_1, @MEMBER_ADDRESS_2, @MEMBER_CITY, @MEMBER_STATE,@ MEMBER_ZIP, @REGION, @MEMBER_PHONE, @LINE_OF_BUSINESS, @MEDICAID_NUMBER, @MEDICARE_NUMBER, @MEDICARE_TYPE, @VENDOR_NAME, @MCO_PROVIDER_NAME, @LOCATION_ID, @EFFECTIVE_DATE, @EXPIRATION_DATE, @SERVICE_CATEGORY, @DETAIL_NUMBERS, @SERVICE_CODE, @MODIFIER_1, @MODIFIER_2, @MODIFIER_3, @MODIFIER_4, @SUNDAY_UNITS, @MONDAY_UNITS, @TUESDAY_UNITS, @WEDNESDAY_UNITS, @THURSDAY_UNITS, @FRIDAY_UNITS, @SATURDAY_UNITS, @TOTAL_UNITS, @NOTES_TO_PROVIDER, @CASE_TYPE, @STATUS, @ALTERNATIVE_CASE_NUMBERS, @SERVICES_CT_ID)");
```

to this:

```
SqlCommand updateTable = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AuthSubmitAppLog (RECEIVED, STATUS_COMMENTS, AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER, CASE_MANAGER, ENTER_DATE, UPDATE_DATE, COMPLETED_BY, COMPLETED_DATETIME, CONTRACT_ENROLL_DATE, CONTRACT_DISENROLL_DATE, DIAGNOSIS_CODE, AUTHORIZATION_TYPE, AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_DETAIL, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_ID, MEMBERSHIP_ID, MEMBER_ADDRESS_1, MEMBER_ADDRESS_2, MEMBER_CITY, MEMBER_STATE, MEMBER_ZIP, REGION, MEMBER_PHONE, LINE_OF_BUSINESS, MEDICAID_NUMBER, MEDICARE_NUMBER, MEDICARE_TYPE, VENDOR_NAME, MCO_PROVIDER_NAME, LOCATION_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRATION_DATE, SERVICE_CATEGORY, DETAIL_NUMBERS, SERVICE_CODE, MODIFIER_1, MODIFIER_2, MODIFIER_3, MODIFIER_4, SUNDAY_UNITS, MONDAY_UNITS, TUESDAY_UNITS, WEDNESDAY_UNITS, THURSDAY_UNITS, FRIDAY_UNITS, SATURDAY_UNITS, TOTAL_UNITS, NOTES_TO_PROVIDER, CASE_TYPE, STATUS, ALTERNATIVE_CASE_NUMBERS, SERVICES_CT_ID) VALUES (@RECEIVED, @STATUS_COMMENTS, @AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER, @CASE_MANAGER, @ENTER_DATE, @UPDATE_DATE, @COMPLETED_BY, @COMPLETED_DATETIME, @CONTRACT_ENROLL_DATE, @CONTRACT_DISENROLL_DATE, @DIAGNOSIS_CODE, @AUTHORIZATION_TYPE, @AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_DETAIL, @MEMBER_NAME, @MEMBER_ID, @MEMBERSHIP_ID, @MEMBER_ADDRESS_1, @MEMBER_ADDRESS_2, @MEMBER_CITY, @MEMBER_STATE, @MEMBER_ZIP, @REGION, @MEMBER_PHONE, @LINE_OF_BUSINESS, @MEDICAID_NUMBER, @MEDICARE_NUMBER, @MEDICARE_TYPE, @VENDOR_NAME, @MCO_PROVIDER_NAME, @LOCATION_ID, @EFFECTIVE_DATE, @EXPIRATION_DATE, @SERVICE_CATEGORY, @DETAIL_NUMBERS, @SERVICE_CODE, @MODIFIER_1, @MODIFIER_2, @MODIFIER_3, @MODIFIER_4, @SUNDAY_UNITS, @MONDAY_UNITS, @TUESDAY_UNITS, @WEDNESDAY_UNITS, @THURSDAY_UNITS, @FRIDAY_UNITS, @SATURDAY_UNITS, @TOTAL_UNITS, @NOTES_TO_PROVIDER, @CASE_TYPE, @STATUS, @ALTERNATIVE_CASE_NUMBERS, @SERVICES_CT_ID)");
```

Answer (score 1):

[<kbd>**`Formatting your SQL code`**</kbd>](http://poorsql.com/) reveals the error:

```
INSERT INTO AuthSubmitAppLog (
    RECEIVED
    ,STATUS_COMMENTS
    ,AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER
    ,CASE_MANAGER
    ,ENTER_DATE
    ,UPDATE_DATE
    ,COMPLETED_BY
    ,COMPLETED_DATETIME
    ,CONTRACT_ENROLL_DATE
    ,CONTRACT_DISENROLL_DATE
    ,DIAGNOSIS_CODE
    ,AUTHORIZATION_TYPE
    ,AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_DETAIL
    ,MEMBER_NAME
    ,MEMBER_ID
    ,MEMBERSHIP_ID
    ,MEMBER_ADDRESS_1
    ,MEMBER_ADDRESS_2
    ,MEMBER_CITY
    ,MEMBER_STATE
    ,MEMBER_ZIP
    ,REGION
    ,MEMBER_PHONE
    ,LINE_OF_BUSINESS
    ,MEDICAID_NUMBER
    ,MEDICARE_NUMBER
    ,MEDICARE_TYPE
    ,VENDOR_NAME
    ,MCO_PROVIDER_NAME
    ,LOCATION_ID
    ,EFFECTIVE_DATE
    ,EXPIRATION_DATE
    ,SERVICE_CATEGORY
    ,DETAIL_NUMBERS
    ,SERVICE_CODE
    ,MODIFIER_1
    ,MODIFIER_2
    ,MODIFIER_3
    ,MODIFIER_4
    ,SUNDAY_UNITS
    ,MONDAY_UNITS
    ,TUESDAY_UNITS
    ,WEDNESDAY_UNITS
    ,THURSDAY_UNITS
    ,FRIDAY_UNITS
    ,SATURDAY_UNITS
    ,TOTAL_UNITS
    ,NOTES_TO_PROVIDER
    ,CASE_TYPE
    ,STATUS
    ,ALTERNATIVE_CASE_NUMBERS
    ,SERVICES_CT_ID
    )
VALUES (
    @RECEIVED
    ,@STATUS_COMMENTS
    ,@AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER
    ,@CASE_MANAGER
    ,@ENTER_DATE
    ,@UPDATE_DATE
    ,@COMPLETED_BY
    ,@COMPLETED_DATETIME
    ,@CONTRACT_ENROLL_DATE
    ,@CONTRACT_DISENROLL_DATE
    ,@DIAGNOSIS_CODE
    ,@AUTHORIZATION_TYPE
    ,@AUTHORIZATION_TYPE_DETAIL
    ,@MEMBER_NAME
    ,@MEMBER_ID
    ,@MEMBERSHIP_ID
    ,@MEMBER_ADDRESS_1
    ,@MEMBER_ADDRESS_2
    ,@MEMBER_CITY
    ,@MEMBER_STATE
    ,@ MEMBER_ZIP
    ,@REGION
    ,@MEMBER_PHONE
    ,@LINE_OF_BUSINESS
    ,@MEDICAID_NUMBER
    ,@MEDICARE_NUMBER
    ,@MEDICARE_TYPE
    ,@VENDOR_NAME
    ,@MCO_PROVIDER_NAME
    ,@LOCATION_ID
    ,@EFFECTIVE_DATE
    ,@EXPIRATION_DATE
    ,@SERVICE_CATEGORY
    ,@DETAIL_NUMBERS
    ,@SERVICE_CODE
    ,@MODIFIER_1
    ,@MODIFIER_2
    ,@MODIFIER_3
    ,@MODIFIER_4
    ,@SUNDAY_UNITS
    ,@MONDAY_UNITS
    ,@TUESDAY_UNITS
    ,@WEDNESDAY_UNITS
    ,@THURSDAY_UNITS
    ,@FRIDAY_UNITS
    ,@SATURDAY_UNITS
    ,@TOTAL_UNITS
    ,@NOTES_TO_PROVIDER
    ,@CASE_TYPE
    ,@STATUS
    ,@ALTERNATIVE_CASE_NUMBERS
    ,@SERVICES_CT_ID
    )
```

Particularly here:

```
...
 ,@MEMBER_CITY
 ,@MEMBER_STATE
 ,@ MEMBER_ZIP   <--
 ,@REGION
 ,@MEMBER_PHONE
 ,@LINE_OF_BUSINESS
...
```

You have a space between `@` and `MEMBER_ZIP`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space from the variable '@ MEMBER_ZIP'